# App submission with coming soon alert

Tags: ios, app-store

I am new in ios development. I have created one app, in this app some features are not available right now. So my question is can i submit my app to app store with same design by giving coming soon alert for those features. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that your app will be rejected if you include such an alert.  Refer to section 2.1 of the App Review Guidelines:

> **2.1 App Completeness**
>
> Submissions to App Review should be final versions with all necessary metadata and fully functional URLs included; placeholder text, empty websites, and other temporary content should be scrubbed before submission. Make sure your app has been tested on-device for bugs and stability before you submit it, and include demo account info (and turn on your back-end service!) if your app includes a login. If you offer in-app purchases in your app, make sure they are complete, up-to-date, and visible to the reviewer, or that you explain why not in your review notes. Please don’t treat App Review as a software testing service. We will reject incomplete app bundles and binaries that crash or exhibit obvious technical problems.

And

> **2.2 Beta Testing**
>
> Demos, betas, and trial versions of your app don’t belong on the App Store...

You should remove all reference to "future functions" and put it back in when the function is available.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have one more question apple will approve my app if i redirect to my website for those features using web view that is those features are implemented on my website but not in my app.

Comment: it'd be useful to add the link to the source, so it can be checked for updates on the content

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as per my knowledge you can submit but it must not crash on `iphone` or `ipad` and must follow all the guidelines of apple. Because coming soon is on kind of `UI` of your app so i don't think that it will be rejected due to this kind of stuff.

You should refer [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) for more details.